# There is no row at position 0. IndexOutofRangeException

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, combobox

whenever i select data from database and show in combobox it shows error IndexOutOfRange was unhandled There is no row at position 0.

```
str = "select * from [Inventory_Remove] where [Inventory_r_id]=" & selectedRow.Cells(0).Value & ""
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cn)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds, "Inventory_Remove")
            If ds.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows.Count - 1
                    sell_inventory_id.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(0).ToString
                    name.SelectedIndex = name.FindString(ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(1).ToString)
                    size.SelectedIndex = size.FindString(ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(2).ToString)
                    piece.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(3).ToString
                    sell_inventory_date.Value = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(4).ToString
                    description.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(5).ToString
                    type.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(6).ToString
                    If name.Text = "Rumali" Then
                        ppp2.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(7).ToString
                    Else
                        ppp.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(7).ToString
                    End If
                    totalprice.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(8).ToString
                Next
            End If
```

here is my code where name and size is combobox and it shows error on line `size.SelectedIndex = size.FindString(ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)(2).ToString)` and when form load i'm load data in size when name's index change may be that's why error cause

Comment: That's rather curious? If you comment that line out, does the next reference to `ds.Tables("Invetory_Remove").Rows(i)` work as expected?

Comment: Nope still get same error on next line error

Comment: Is there anything else operating on the dataset/datatable at the same time?  What happens if you try to get a reference to the first row as you get into the loop like so: `Dim row = ds.Tables("Inventory_Remove").Rows(i)` and subsequently use that object instead of addressing it through the dataset at each line?

Comment: Same error sir :(